# How to apply Ford-Fulkerson algorithm to a graph to find maximum flow in a flow network?

Tags: algorithm, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

Can someone please direct me to a site where step-by-step instruction is given on how to apply ford-fulkerson method on a graph to find the maximum flow.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Best I know ( [link](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=maxFlow) ), wikipedia ( [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) ) and first alternative Google hit ( [Link](http://www-b2.is.tokushima-u.ac.jp/~ikeda/suuri/maxflow/Maxflow.shtml) ).

> ### Ford-Fulkerson Labeling Algorithm
>
> - (Initialization) Let x be an initial feasible flow (e.g. x(e) = 0
>     for all e in E).
> - (Flow augmentation) If there are no augmenting path from s to t on the
>     residual network, then stop. The
>     present x is a max flow. If there is a
>     flow augmenting path p, replace the
>     flow x as
>     2.
>
>   - x(e)=x(e)+delta if e is a forward arc on p.
>   - x(e)=x(e)-delta if e is a backward arc on p. where delta is a minimum
>       value of residual capacity on p.
>       Repeat this step.
>
> Source code example: [Java](http://www-b2.is.tokushima-u.ac.jp/~ikeda/suuri/maxflow/Maxflow.java2.Source%3a)

Comment: Thanks for your help. found this fantastic explanation:http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=maxFlow

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm

Comment: I've looked at the wikipedia article, it did not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

also interesting is the min-cut theorem. the maximum amount of flow passing from the source to the sink is equal to the minimum cut of edges and their flow. i just flunked on that question in school :(

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem